# 'Document was not saved yet' state in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

When you open an application (Example: TextEdit) and write something, the X red ball in the top left hand corner becomes a red ball with a black ball inside until you save the file. That happens in any Mac program if you have changed something of the original file and didn't saved yet.

My question is: how can I do this in Objective-C for my application? How can I reach this 'state'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comes automatically if you use an [`NSDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) based architecture.

or use the `NSWindow` method: [`setDocumentEdited:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setDocumentEdited%3a)

Comment: There is some way to bind all the text fields of the window to this method? For example: if someone change a field value, the program will run `[window setDocumentEdited:TRUE]` automatically.

Comment: Using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164471/listen-to-a-value-change-of-my-text-field) combined to the `setDocumentEdited:` seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot.