# How to properly use delegation for NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

Im trying to implement a delegate for a **NSTextField** object so I can detect the user input in real time and give some feedback about no allowed input in that particular field.
 Especially, I want to simulate the `onChange()` method from JavaScript, detecting the user input in real time and show him a warning if it is writing a non supported value.

i.e. The app have a text field it only accept numeric values from 0 to 255 (like RGB values) and I want to know when the user is writing not numeric values or out of range values to instantly show him a warning message or change the text field background color, just a visual hint to let him know the input it's wrong.

[image]
[image]

Like you see on the pictures above, I want to show a warning sign every time the user inputs a forbidden value in the text field.

I have been reading a lot of the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW1) but I don't understand which delegate to implement (`NSTextFieldDelegate`, `NSTextDelegate`, or `NSTextViewDelegate`), also, I have no idea how to implement it in my `AppDelegate.m` file and which method use and how to get the notification of user editing.

Right now, I already set the Delegate in my `init` method with something like this `[self.textField setDelegate:self];` but I don't understand how to use it or which method implements.

Comment: I would recommend you to use an `NSNumberFormatter` for those kind of things. There is even an `NSTextField` with a number formatter in the sidebar of interface builder.

Comment: thank you for your recommendation, but I already have the formatter working fine, but I need to implement a visual warning just for user friendliness matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution using the information posted in this question... [Listen to a value change of my text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164471/listen-to-a-value-change-of-my-text-field)

First of all I have to declare the NSTextFieldDelegate in the AppDelegate.h file

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate>
```

After that, I have to instantiate the delegate for the NSTextField object I want to modify while the user update it in the AppDelegate.m file.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.textField setDelegate:self];
}
```

Finally, I implement the methods to detect field editing with the changes I want to set.

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTextField *textField = [notification object];
    if ([textField doubleValue] < 0 | [textField doubleValue] > 255) {
        textField.textColor = [NSColor redColor];
    }
}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTextField *textField = [notification object];
    if ([textField resignFirstResponder]) {
        textField.textColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your class conform to the [NSTextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTextFieldDelegate) protocol. It need's to be that protocol because in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/delegate) it says the type of protocol the delegate conforms to.

@interface MyClass : NSObject

And implement the delegate's methods (just add them to your code). Example

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{
}
```

EDIT:

I think in your case it would be better to replace the TextField for a TextView and use a [NSTextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textView%3ashouldChangeTextInRange%3areplacementString%3a), in the delegate, the method of most interst of you should be

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)affectedCharRange replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString
{
    BOOL isValid = ... // Check here if replacementString is valid (only digits, ...)
    return isValid; // If you return false, the user edition is cancelled
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how should I use this `textShouldBeginEditing` method because that's what I'm trying to use, but I don't understand how. I'm still too new in Cocoa Development (just like 2 weeks so far).

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what to do, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I already updated my question with some pictures explaining my idea.