# User input in textfield

Tags: objective-c, input, uitextfield, ios9

I have three textfields where the user enter their info. If the info format is not correct I will display a warning message in red color, then let them type in the new info. I tried to use a `while` loop to wait for their new info then go through the same `if` statements. If their new info is correct then once the button is pressed, we go to another storyboard. It didn't work for some reason. Can you tell me what I can do to display the warning message then wait for new input without going to the second storyboard just yet?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While loop? No way!

What you are looking for is implementation of one of the following `UITextFieldDelegate` methods:

To put validation up-front as user type a character:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

To put validation once user is done typing:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Go through this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) to understand it in detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am just starting to learn objective c and Xcode. Right now I'm taking an online course, could you recommend any books that might help me significantly?

Comment: I had recently suggested someone on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669622/learning-ios-programming-the-apple-way/32669743#32669743. Check if this help you. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like this should solve your question: [Listen to a value change of my text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164471/listen-to-a-value-change-of-my-text-field)
Set a delegate for your field and have the delegate implement an onChange method where you validate the input.